# mysql order by agregate functions work incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, min

I have problem with aggregate functions in order by. Problem is that the output is incorrectly sorted. Can even be aggregate functions in order by? They worked for me every time...

> (problem is somewhere in order by MIN() function).

I tried convert all variables to same data type, but that didn't work as well.

**query:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  COALESCE(MIN(IF(FIND_IN_SET("O", p.campaign), NULL, p.price) * (1 + v.vat / 100) * (1 - p.discount / 100)), p.price) as test,
  p.id as `id`

FROM
  products p
  LEFT JOIN products_variations pv ON p.id = pv.id_product
  LEFT JOIN photos_products_relation ppr ON p.id = ppr.id_product AND ppr.show_in_lead = 'Y'
  LEFT JOIN producers pr ON p.producer = pr.id
  INNER JOIN products_in_sections ps ON p.id = ps.id_product
  INNER JOIN vats v ON p.vat = v.id

WHERE ((pv.figure = 'Y') OR (pv.figure IS NULL)) AND (pr.active = 'Y' OR pr.id IS NULL) AND (
  ((COALESCE(pv.in_store, p.in_store) > 0) AND (ps.id_section IN (1868, 1855, 1758, 1746, 1875, 1947, 1870, 1952, 1895, 1942, 1737, 1741, 1744, 1828, 1887, 1762, 1773, 1893, 1781, 1897, 1929, 1920, 1896, 1908, 1751, 1775, 1782, 1770, 1778)) AND (p.figure = 'Y') AND
   (NOT FIND_IN_SET('O', coalesce(pv.campaign, '')))) AND (1)) AND (p.id_model IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY p.id_model
ORDER BY COALESCE(MIN(IF(FIND_IN_SET("O", p.campaign), NULL, p.price) * (1 + v.vat / 100) * (1 - p.discount / 100)), p.price) ASC
LIMIT 36 OFFSET 0;
```

**output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeK9f.png

As you see, column test is incorrectly sorted...

normally I would do

```
ORDER BY test
```

that works, but I dont want field 'test' in output.

(original query has many more select fields).

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's not working, I can't see what is wrong. You can always do something like this if you have to.

```
SELECT ... (All columns but test)
FROM (  your query here as subquery) a
ORDER BY test ASC
```